# Does Windows use hybrid sleep by default?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hybrid-sleep

I'm on Windows 7, and I've got "Enable hybrid sleep" set to "On" in the setting of my power plan.

Does it mean that Windows puts my computer into hybrid sleep mode every time I click "Sleep" in the Start Menu or just a regular sleep mode?

I could test it myself by disconnecting the PC from power supply while it's asleep, but I don't feel like trying because I don't want to lose any data or make my software/hardware unstable.

Comment: Okay, folks, let's calm down a little. No reason for a heated debate there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) states:

> When hybrid sleep is turned on, putting your computer into sleep automatically puts your computer into hybrid sleep.

So, yes, it is generally a safe assumption. However, keep in mind that the save-to-disk part of hybrid sleep is not instantaneous (could take a minute), and hybrid sleep may be accidentally disabled without any outward indication, so it is best to avoid a loss of power.

I would recommend explicit hibernation if you are anticipating a loss of power or do not need to use the computer for an extended period of time (or if you can afford to wait half a minute for it to resume).

Comment: When hybrid sleep is on, only *Sleep* option is available in the menu, *Hibernate* is removed.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Yes. This only affects the start menu, not the ability to hibernate - there are many ways to hibernate with hybrid sleep enabled.

Comment: For the reader, such as this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1293422/71936.