# My Windows 10 doesn't have an option for hibernate

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

Actually, the sleep mode of Windows 10 is what I needed, though I made a mistake previously, I put the pc in sleep mode, disabled the power, enabled the power and then pressed the Power on button, which basically started it up completely, this is why I thought the sleep mode didn't work properly.

---

I hate having to open up all programs and folders again after shutting windows down, this is why I would like to use the hibernate-mode to save energy during the night, but to immediately start working the next morning.
Sadly, my current Win 10 Pro installation doesn't have the hibernate option. I tried activating it through the energy settings, but the option isn't available.

Anybody has experience with this?

[image]

Comment: First off, hibernation is not always available on all computers due to hardware configuration and support of the feature in Windows 10. Unfortunately, I don't speak the language in your picture, so that does me no good. You may want to read this article to see if there are any tips to help you, [How to Enable or Disable Hibernate in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html). If after these steps you still can not use it, please update your question with specifics about what you have tried to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 10 you can update the power settings to put the computer to sleep via the Control Panel or the Power & Sleep settings, which is effectively the same thing as hibernate.

In Cortana type 'Power Settings' in the Ask Me Anything box, and select Edit plan.  Then you can set the timing (i.e., on battery put the computer to sleep after 15 minutes).  Then click Save Changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is really a comment, not an answer since the user specifically states **hibernation**, not **sleep**. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//superuser.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: you are absolutely right! I made a mistake previously, I put the pc in sleep mode, disabled the power, enabled the power and then pressed the Power on button, which basically started it up completely (instead I should have pressed enter instead).

Answer (score 8):

- Go to *Control Panel* → *Hardware and Sound* → *Power Options* (you can also type *Power Options* in the Windows search)
- Click on *Choose what the power buttons do*
- Click on *Change settings that are currently unavailable*
- Check this checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate is disabled by default in Windows 10.  The easiest way to enable hibernate on Windows 10 is:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Select "Command Propt (Admin)
- type 'powercfg /h on`

There are other methods that can be found [here](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/05/windows-10-tutorials-60-how-to-enable-or-disable-hibernate/).

Answer (score 1):

To Hibernate Windows 10, go to the Windows 10 Start menu. Click on the option Power and then choose the Option Hibernate.

If this option is not present then you have to enable this option from the Power Options.

To enable Windows 10 Hibernate Option in Start Menu is a very simple and easy task.

STEP 1: Locate Power Options

First, Open the Control Panel from the Start Menu and then locate Power Options. Then, click on it.
[image]

STEP 2: Set Lid Settings

Once the Power Options windows open up, click on the option “Choose what closing the lid does” located on the left side plane.
[image]

STEP 3: Choose Hibernate Option

Then, click on the link “Change settings that currently unavailable” given on the top side of the Window. After that, you will see that the Hibernate option will become active.

Finally, click on the checkbox of the Hibernate Option and you are good to go.
[image]

AFTER HIBERNATE

[image]

For more info, go here [Windows 10 Hibernate Option in Start Menu - includeguide](https://www.includeguide.com/windows-10-hibernate-option-in-start-menu/)

Answer (score -1):

remember that.
if your Windows in "Tablet Mode" none of the solutions will work.

in this case open "settings" and search "Tablet Mode", then make it off.
you will be switched to "desktop mode"